# Custom Favicon in Sharepoint 2010 My Site

Tags: sharepoint-2010, favicon, mysite

Is it possible to change the favicon for the My Sites in Sharepoint 2010? I've followed Randy Drisgills tutorial for changing the SharePoint site icon and it worked.

http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/11/sp2010-branding-tip-4-easily-show.html

When I've tried to apply the same changes to the My Site master page I see no change. I've been instructed to not overwrite the original favicon so that is not a viable solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated this problem before, and there are possible issues which haven't been mentioned:

1. Icon content type(not exactly SP content type!) - be sure that your icon is bitmap (16x16 px) and has extension "ico" and name "favicon". For example if you create png/jpg and change it's name to favicon.ico - it won't work... You can use [this](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/) site to convert your icons to proper format.
2. Be sure that you check proper masterpage which have mentioned control - simply check source code and look for :

   ```
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="your_path_to_favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
   ```